# Iterate over multiple Pandas columns and get frequency values

Tags: python, pandas

I've this issue I need to iterate over a pandas dataframe with 500 columns, and get a list of columns with only one occurrence for one of the values.

ex:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1, 0, 0 , 0], 'Y': [1, 0, 0 , 1], 'Z': [1, 0, 1 , 1]})
```

What I need :

A list of Columns where the number of minimum occurrences is 1, in this Case X and Z 
because for X we've 1 - 1 time and 0 -3 times, the same with Z, 1 - 3 times and 0 - 1 time, so X and Z have values with only one occurrence.

I've create an iteration through the pandas items

```
for k in df2.columns:
    print(k)
    display(pd.DataFrame(df2[k].value_counts()))
    for p in df2[k].value_counts():
        #pd.DataFrame(df2[k].value_counts()).T.iterrows():
        #if z > 1:
        print("p",p)
        if p==1:
            print(k)
```

I've tested this solution,

```
df2['count'] = df2.groupby(['X', 'Y'], axis=1).cumcount()
```

But the result is a cumulative count by Row, not exactly what I need.

I've try converting into a Series, tested, converted into a Pandas Dataframe, but I'm a bit stuck how iterated over the second loop and select the values

Thank you if you can help

Comment: Will all of the values in the columns only ever be 0 or 1, or is that only for the example?

Comment: Values are only 0 and 1's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would seem to work, based on the given description:

```
[col for col in df2.columns if any(i==1 for i in df2[col].value_counts().values)]

['X', 'Z']
```

Alternately to check each column and print whether it qualifies:

```
for col in df2:
    print(any(i==1 for i in df2[col].value_counts().values))

True
False
True
```